# How to show graph using Achartengine in fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, achartengine

I want to display graph using Achartengine in Fragment. 
In my layout file I have used empty linear layout to add graph returned by createIntent() method 
but it only shows blank screen 
I am using following code

My Fragment activity is as below

pls help

```
public class Analytics_Screen extends Fragment implements OnClickListener,SlideActivity.Callbacks{

View checkanalytics_view;
SlideActivity activity;

LinearLayout graph_container; 

@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        activity = (SlideActivity) getActivity();
        metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
        activity.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
    }

@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        if (checkanalytics_view == null)
        {
            checkanalytics_view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.checkanalytics_screen, null, false);
        }

        activity.OpenLeftmenu(0);
        SlideActivity.registerCallback(this);

        graph_container     = (LinearLayout)checkanalytics_view.findViewById(R.id.graph_container);

        final GraphicalView gv =createIntent();         
        graph_container.addView(gv,new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        return checkanalytics_view;

    }

  public GraphicalView createIntent() 
    {

     //   List<double[]> values = new ArrayList<double[]>();

        System.out.println("==============create Intent Start==========================");
        List<Double> dValues=new ArrayList<Double>();
        dValues.add((double) 5000);
        dValues.add((double) 6000);
        dValues.add((double) 7000);
        dValues.add((double) 8000);
        dValues.add((double) 10000);
        dValues.add((double) 5000);
        dValues.add((double) 25000);
        dValues.add((double) 50000);
        dValues.add((double) 50000);
       // values.add(new double[] { 5000, 7300, 9240,10230, 11300, 10040,14230, 12300, 14240});

        int[] colors = new int[] { Color.parseColor("#77c4d3")};
        XYMultipleSeriesRenderer renderer = buildBarRenderer(colors);
        renderer.setOrientation(Orientation.VERTICAL);
        setChartSettings(renderer, "Analitics", "", "",0.1,
            12.5, 0,50000, Color.BLACK, Color.BLACK);
       renderer.setXLabels(1);
        renderer.setYLabels(10);
        renderer.addXTextLabel(1, "Male");
        renderer.addXTextLabel(2, "Female");
        renderer.addXTextLabel(3, "Age 0-20");
        renderer.addXTextLabel(4, "Age 21-30");
        renderer.addXTextLabel(5, "Age 31-40");
        renderer.addXTextLabel(6, "Age 41-50");
        renderer.addXTextLabel(7, "Age 50+");
        renderer.addXTextLabel(8, "Penciled");
        renderer.addXTextLabel(9, "Attended");
     /*   renderer.addXTextLabel(10, "Oct");
        renderer.addXTextLabel(11, "Nov");
        renderer.addXTextLabel(12, "Dec");*/


        int length = renderer.getSeriesRendererCount();
        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
          SimpleSeriesRenderer seriesRenderer = renderer.getSeriesRendererAt(i);
          seriesRenderer.setDisplayChartValues(true);
        }


        final GraphicalView grfv = ChartFactory.getBarChartView(activity, buildBarDataset(dValues), renderer,Type.DEFAULT);

        System.out.println("===============Graph View=================="+grfv);
        return grfv;
      }

    protected XYMultipleSeriesRenderer buildBarRenderer(int[] colors) {
        XYMultipleSeriesRenderer renderer = new XYMultipleSeriesRenderer();
        renderer.setAxisTitleTextSize(10);
        renderer.setChartTitleTextSize(20);
        renderer.setLabelsTextSize(10);
        renderer.setLegendTextSize(5);
        renderer.setBarSpacing(1);
        renderer.setMarginsColor(Color.parseColor("#EEEDED"));
        renderer.setXLabelsColor(Color.BLACK);
        renderer.setYLabelsColor(0,Color.BLACK);

        renderer.setApplyBackgroundColor(true);
        renderer.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FBFBFC"));
        renderer.setInScroll(true);

        int length = colors.length;
        Log.d("Color Len",""+length);
        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
          SimpleSeriesRenderer r = new SimpleSeriesRenderer();
          r.setColor(colors[i]);
         // r.setChartvalueAngle(-90);

          r.setChartValuesSpacing(25);
          renderer.addSeriesRenderer(r);
        }
        return renderer;
      }

  protected XYMultipleSeriesDataset buildBarDataset(List<Double> values) {
        XYMultipleSeriesDataset dataset = new XYMultipleSeriesDataset();

          CategorySeries series = new CategorySeries("Amount");
         // Double v = values.get(0);
          int seriesLength = values.size();
          for (int k = 0; k < seriesLength; k++) {
            series.add(values.get(k));
          }
          dataset.addSeries(series.toXYSeries());

        return dataset;
      }

  protected void setChartSettings(XYMultipleSeriesRenderer renderer, String title, String xTitle,
          String yTitle, double xMin, double xMax, double yMin, double yMax, int axesColor,
          int labelsColor) {
        renderer.setChartTitle(title);
        renderer.setYLabelsAlign(Align.RIGHT);
        renderer.setXLabelsAlign(Align.RIGHT);
        renderer.setXTitle(xTitle);
        renderer.setYTitle(yTitle);
        renderer.setXAxisMin(xMin);
        renderer.setXAxisMax(xMax);
        renderer.setYAxisMin(yMin);
        renderer.setYAxisMax(yMax);
        renderer.setMargins(new int[] {15,50,50,50 });
        renderer.setAxesColor(axesColor);
        renderer.setLabelsColor(labelsColor);
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this instead

```
protected XYMultipleSeriesRenderer buildBarRenderer(int[] colors)
    {
        XYMultipleSeriesRenderer renderer = new XYMultipleSeriesRenderer();
        renderer.setAxisTitleTextSize(10);
        renderer.setChartTitleTextSize(20);
        renderer.setLabelsTextSize(10);
        renderer.setLegendTextSize(5);
        renderer.setBarSpacing(1);
        renderer.setMarginsColor(Color.parseColor("#EEEDED"));
        renderer.setXLabelsColor(Color.BLACK);
        renderer.setYLabelsColor(0, Color.BLACK);

        renderer.setApplyBackgroundColor(true);
        renderer.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FBFBFC"));
        renderer.setInScroll(true);

        int length = colors.length;
        Log.d("Color Len", "" + length);

            XYSeriesRenderer r = new XYSeriesRenderer();
            r.setColor(colors[0]);
            // r.setChartvalueAngle(-90);

            // r.setChartValuesSpacing(25);
            renderer.addSeriesRenderer(r);

        return renderer;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if my answer can solve your problem, but I was successful in displaying a graph in a fragment. This is what I did, following is my fragment Layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#4DDBFF">

<LinearLayout
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/graphLayout"
android:background="#000000" />

</LinearLayout>
```

I created 2 classes (a)SideFragment.java (b) LineGraph.java

LineGraph.java generates the graph and the following method return the view in this class

```
public GraphicalView getView(Context context){
GraphicalView view =  ChartFactory.getLineChartView(context, mDataset, mRenderer);
return view;
}
```

In SideFragment.java I have a GraphicalView variable which is initialised in onCreate() by calling LineGraph.getView() as follows

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    context = getActivity().getApplicationContext();
    line = new LineGraph();

    graphview = line.getView(context);
}
```

And I add this Graphview is attached to the fragment Layout in onStart()

```
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    Log.i(TAG, "onStart");
    LinearLayout fragmentLayout = (LinearLayout)     view.findViewById(R.id.graphLayout);

    fragmentLayout.addView(graphview);
}
```

Since I am generating the graph dynamically I keep repainting the GraphView on a background thread (AsyncTask) which I have initiated in onActivityCreated()

```
protected void onProgressUpdate(String... values) {
        Log.i(TAG, "onProgressUpdate");

        graphview.repaint();

        super.onProgressUpdate(values);
    }
```

I hope this could be of some help to you.